# Can't Free caller component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to free a component when i click it. So, i've written the simplest code i could imagine to achieve this: a procedure that frees it's sender. But on Delphi 7 (Tried on Delphi XE 10 and it worked with no errors) it sometimes throws an Access Violation or Abstract Error randomly. The easiest way to replicate this is to insert like 30 Buttons and assign an onclick procedure with the code below, then click them.

I've tried the two codes below, both on onclick:

```
procedure FreeMe(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TButton(Sender).Free;
end;
```

or

```
procedure FreeMe(Sender: TObject);
begin
    (Sender as TButton).Free;
end;
```

Comment: Bottom line is you can't do this because the event handler is called by the button object, and when the event handler returns, execution returns to methods of the button object. Which you just killed. So now you have methods executing for which `Self` is not valid, having been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks in advice David. I saw your duplicates sugestions and maybe I can try the PostMessage one. How can I free a button using the post message?

Comment: Depends on the type of button, VCL or FMX, etc.

Comment: It's standard VCL

Comment: The dupes match your scenario perfectly. I don't think there is any more to say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the dups show how to make derivative classes free themselves, not how to free standard stock components.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are confusing the question and the answer. You should have left this closed and added an answer at one of the dupes. By reopening this you break all the links. Marking questions as duplicates is incredibly useful to future visitors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you can debate it all you want, the dups mentioned were similar but not really duplicates of this question. Different scenarios with different answers than this question. That is why I reopened this question. That is all I'm saying on this.

Comment: @remy It all comes down to whether you want to help one person or many. You chose to do the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delay the freeing until after the button's `OnClick` event handier has fully exited.  It is important that the freeing happens when the object being freed is idle and not in the middle of processing anything.

One way to do that is to use `PostMessage()`, eg:

```pascal
var
  MyReleaseWnd: HWND;

procedure TMyMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyReleaseWnd := AllocateHWnd(MyReleaseWndProc);
end;

procedure TMyMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   DeallocateHWnd(MyReleaseWnd);
end;

procedure TMyMainForm.MyReleaseWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = CM_RELEASE then
    TObject(Msg.LParam).Free
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(MyReleaseWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure DelayFreeMe(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(MyReleaseWnd, CM_RELEASE, 0, LPARAM(Sender));
end;
```

Alternatively, in 10.2 Tokyo and later, you can use `TThread.ForceQueue()` instead:

```pascal
procedure DelayFreeMe(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, Sender.Free);
end;
```

Either way, you can then do this:

```pascal
procedure TSomeForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DelayFreeMe(Sender);
end;
```